# How to change Button size in Android?

Tags: java, android, button, resize

I am trying to change the button size dynamically, but after using `setWidth()` and `setHeight()` nothing happens.

This is my code...

```
GridLayout grid = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.grid);
grid.setColumnCount(10);
grid.setRowCount(10);
cells = new Button[100];
for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { 
    cells[i] = new Button(this);
    cells[i].setWidth(grid.getWidth()/10);
    cells[i].setHeight(grid.getHeight()/10);
    grid.addView(cells[i]);
}
```

Any ideas/solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out on my own and it was very simple, I feel stupid for overlooking it.

```
grid.addView(cells[i], display.getWidth()/grid.getColumnCount(), display.getWidth()/grid.getColumnCount());
```

In this line of code I add the button to the layout with the "cells[i]" while the trailing two parameters tell the view what size I want the button to be.

Another example:

```
addView(myButton, 100, 200);
```

Above the addView is adding myButton with 100 pixel width by 200 pixel height.

Answer (score 3):

LayoutParams should solve the issue:

This in an example of how it should work taken from another stackOverflow post:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myButton.getLayoutParams(); 
params.width = 400;    
myButton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to call `invalidate` method. If the view is visible, `onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)` will be called at some point in the future. This must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI thread, call `postInvalidate()`.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29